# QtConcurrent::mappedReduced

Tags: c++, qt, qtconcurrent

to improve my program, i want to use Qtconcurrent to parallelize my audio process.
Unfortunately, i have many errors and i don't know why ...

In my *.pro : QT += concurrent

I use minGW with Qt 5.3.1 and when i try to build, the compiler said "forming reference to void" (qvector.h).

Here my main code :

```
void Reduce(QString& result, const QString& txt){ result += txt;}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QFuture<QString> res = QtConcurrent::mappedReduced(wavSoundsList, &BenchFFT::process, Reduce, QtConcurrent::OrderedReduce);

    res.waitForFinished();
    qDebug("%s",qPrintable(res.result()));

   return a.exec();
}
```

and my class :

```
class BenchFFT 
{
public:
    BenchFFT();
    QString process(const QString &wavFile);

private:

    QString soundsPath;
    QStringList wavSoundsList;

    //Audio file
    bool OpenWav(const QString WavPath, SndfileHandle &file);

    //FFT
    bool ComputeFFT(SndfileHandle file);
    double Blackman(int x, int iWindowSize);
    //Intel IPP7
    IppsFFTSpec_R_64f * pFFTSpec;
    Ipp64f* data; // source FFT
    Ipp64fc* fftResult; // dest FFT
};
```

if someone can explain me my mistakes.thx :)

Edit : now i don't have build error with this modification

```
QFuture<QString> res = QtConcurrent::mappedReduced(wavSoundsList, std::tr1::bind(&BenchFFT::process, BenchFFT(), std::tr1::placeholders::_1), &Reduce, QtConcurrent::OrderedReduce);
```

but my program crashed .....

Comment: On which line? Post errors literally.

Comment: Maybe you need to write `&Reduce` instead of `Reduce` in `QFuture<QString> res = QtConcurrent::mappedReduced(wavSoundsList, &BenchFFT::process, Reduce,...` call?

Comment: with &Reduce same error .... and the first error line "qvector.h:439:1: error: forming reference to void"

Comment: @Gamso, than show the code (line in your own code) that causes the error.

Comment: the line with "QtConcurrent::mappedReduced" causes the error. If i call the function "BenchFFT::process" only i don't have error and it's work ....

Comment: try: std::function<QString(const QString&)> map=&BenchFFT::process;
 QFuture<QString> res = QtConcurrent::mappedReduced(wavSoundsList, map, Reduce, QtConcurrent::OrderedReduce);